# Docker Stuck at building Golang inside AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, go, alpine-linux

Im going crazy here... im trying to create a docker container with this file:

```
#Docker
FROM golang:alpine as builder

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git make gcc libc-dev

# download, cache and install deps
WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

# copy and compiled the app
COPY . .
RUN make ditto

# start a new stage from scratch
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates

WORKDIR /root/

# copy the prebuilt binary from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app/_build/ditto .
COPY --from=builder /app/send-email-report.sh /usr/bin/

ENTRYPOINT ["./ditto"]
```

Running: `docker build .`

On my Pc it works perfect
BUT in my AWS instance of EC2 same code:

```
docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon    108kB
Step 1/13 : FROM golang:1.18-alpine as builder
 ---> 155ead2e66ca
Step 2/13 : RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git make gcc libc-dev
 ---> Running in 1d3adab601f3
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.16.0-99-g5b6c75ce95 [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main]
v3.16.0-108-ge392af4f2e [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community]
OK: 17022 distinct packages available
```

And get Stuck there...
It was working fine in the past, I think nobody has change on that docker file and folder...

Can somebody help me? please

Comment: Could be Security Group related. Is you instance able to retrieve those packages?

Comment: Can you explain to me what are you seeing in the log that im missing? Im not understanding what package is not able to download the container... in the "print" there is not a error message or information that helps me...

But just for testing, I try to download the 4 files showed on the log with wget:

https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main
https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community
they all worked

Comment: I think that the problem is with  "OK: 17022 distinct packages available".
But even looking on google I can't find anything useful

Comment: I don't see anything particular in the logs. It's just that a stuck process might point to a Security Group issue. Did you check the Outbound Rules of the SG?